# optaplanner collision with pinned entities

Tags: optaplanner

In my optaplanner course-scheduling project the user adds some fix lectures before the start of the planning algorithm. They are made unmovable by using `@PlanningPin`.

The problem is: once they are pinned they are not propagated down the ConstratinsStream. So the collision constraint doesnt work and they are not colliding with the non fixed entities.
Here is a minimal non working hello-world-constraint:

constraint definition:

```
factory.from(Lecture.class).filter(t -> helloWorld(t)).penalize...
```

hello world function:

```
public static boolean helloWorld(Lecture m) {
     if (m.isFixed()) {System.out.println("hello world"); }
     return true;
}
```

Am I correct to assume that fixed entities should be propagated down the stream and if yes, can someone give any tip on where my error could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities are propegated down the stream, regardless if they are pinned or not.

But if an entity is pinned and the planning variable is `null`, then just like with non-pinned entities, it will not be propagated with `.from()`, only with `.fromUnfiltered()`. The difference is that non-pinned entity will be made non-null by the Construction Heuristic.

Comment: Thanks, that helped: I have two planning variables (timeslot and room) and the room was null with the fixed entities, so they were not propagated. I somehow thought only the timeslot to be fixed, but the optaplanner @PlanningPin fixes both variables at once. So the room will stay null.